# Delta Lake Merge - Multiple "whenMatchedUpdate" Do Not Work (no error thrown)

Tags: pyspark, merge, databricks, delta-lake

**Environment:**

- Databricks 11.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12)
  -- NOTE: Also tried lower versions including 10.4, 10.5, and 11
- Pyspark

When Merging using Delta Lake I cannot set more than one condition on "whenMatchedUpdate". As you can see from the example below 2 (or more) "whenMatchUpdate" calls and the behavior of this always applies to the first call (i.e the Client one will be set but Description won't despite the value being there).

```
destDeltaTable = DeltaTable.forName(spark, "DestinationTable")

merge = (
    destDeltaTable.alias("Dest")
    .merge(
        source_df.alias("Source"),
        """
        (Source.id == Dest.id)

        """,
    )
    .whenMatchedUpdate(condition="Dest.Client IS NULL", set={"Client": col("Source.Client")})
    .whenMatchedUpdate(condition="Dest.Description IS NULL", set={"Description": col("Source.Description")})
    ...
    ...
    whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
)

merge.execute()
```

The goal is to be able to have multiple conditions during my upsert using "whenMatchedUpdate".

#### Example Data:

**Source** (Delta Table)

| ID | Client | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | Something! |

**Destination** (Delta Table)

| ID | Client | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL |

The expected result would be for the data to be upserted and the match cases met (i.e both Client and Description should contain values from the Source)

**Final Expected:**

**Destination** (Delta Table)

| ID | Client | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | Something! |

**Actual Result**

**Destination** (Delta Table)

| ID | Client | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | NULL |

If we add more or switch these around we see that the logic is only applied to the first `whenMatchedUpdate(..)`.

Comment: can you show your data? does row have both Client & Description as nulls?

Comment: Yes, both values are null in the "FinalTable", when a new record is inserted it contains values for both Client & Description--however, only Client would get updated since it comes first in the logic. I'll update ticket with more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior as it resembles the if/else in traditional programming languages:

```
if something:
  do1
elif something2:
  do2
else:
  do3
```

You just need to add a condition when both columns are nulls and update both of them.

Comment: Thank you! I added the additional cases and it worked. I will have to be very verbose here to catch all.

Comment: One possibility could be to switch to SQL and generate all conditions programmatically

Comment: Makes sense, I was also able to achieve the results with building out the combinations for a given list. (i.e given [Client,Description,etc.,] generate combination starting with the largest base case).